# How to create a .txt sidecar file whenever a Windows 10 game recording is finished and populate it with data like 'app', 'date' + custom tags

Tags: automation, windows-10, event-listener

I'd like to automate the process of creating sidecar .txt files (.json could work too) to finished Windows 10 recordings (Windows Game Bar).

These files are usually named `{app}{date}.mp4` and the sidecar file should mimic that while adding .txt or .json at the end, like so: `{app}{date}.mp4.txt`

I was wondering if there's a programmatical way to create some kind event listener to create such a sidecar file whenever a recording is finished, and preferably to populate it with default tags (1 per line)

So far only tried googling for an answer, but did not find anything relevant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell script (based on some modifications to one written by ChatGPT) that creates a file system watcher for the folder C:\Users\YourName\Videos\Captures and triggers a script block that creates a .mp4.txt sidecar file with the same name as the .mp4 file and populates it with some data

```
# Define the folder to watch
$folder = "C:\Users\YourName\Videos\Captures"

# Define the filter for .mp4 files
$filter = "*.mp4"

# Create a file system watcher object
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $false
EnableRaisingEvents = $true
}

# Define the script block to run when a file is changed
$changeAction = {
# Get the full path and name of the changed file
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name

# Write some information to the console
Write-Host "The file $name was changed at $(Get-Date)"

# Create a .txt sidecar file with the same name as the .mp4 file
$sidecar = $path -replace ".mp4$", ".mp4.txt"

# Populate the sidecar file with some data
# You can customize this part as you wish

<# variable names #>
$date = "Date: $(Get-Date)"

$tags = "
$date
foo
bar
"

[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($sidecar, $tags)

}

# Register an event handler for the Changed event of the watcher
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher -EventName Changed -Action $changeAction
```

You can save this script as a .ps1 file and run it by right-clicking on it and selecting Run with PowerShell.